# Openlayer and vuejs - Error on addEventlistener

Tags: vue.js, openlayers

I'm trying to integrate openlayer with vuejs.

Whatever i try i still have the following error : Uncaught TypeError: target.addEventListener is not a function

After some research i found some example in vuejs but don't really help me.

I have also try vuelayers. I got the same error.

Any idea ?

EDIT :

openlayers version : "ol": "^6.4.3",

vuejs version :  "vue": "^2.6.11",

```
<template>
    <div class="w3-content">
        <div ref="map-root" id="map"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import 'ol/ol.css';
    import { Map, View } from 'ol';
    import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
    import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';


    export default {
        data() {
            return {

            }
        },
        methods: {
             initMap() {
             const map = new Map({
                    target: this.$refs['map-root'],
                    layers: [
                        new TileLayer({
                            source: new OSM()
                        })
                    ],
                    view: new View({
                        center: [0, 0],
                        zoom: 0
                    })
                });
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.initMap();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you add code how you use OpenLayers in Vue.js?

Comment: Please not in comments. Add it to your post as formatted code block.

Comment: Also please indiacte a version of OL